# Method suggestion on visual studio code

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

I have installed node.js:

```
node -v
v10.0.0
npm -v
5.6.0
```

and vsCode version: 1.23.1

```
Version 1.23.1
Commit d0182c3417d225529c6d5ad24b7572815d0de9ac
Date 2018-05-10T17:11:17.614Z
Shell 1.7.12
Renderer 58.0.3029.110
Node 7.9.0
Architecture x64
```

For starting Node.js on VsCode i have required `path` and `os` core module like below:

```
const path = require('path');
const os = require('os');
```

Now when i am going to use these const variables, vscode did not suggest any method of these modules?

[image]

I just installed node.js and vscode, that is mean i did not install and library yet.

Comment: Maybe try upgrading your vscode (currently v1.26.1) - the automatic type acquisition functionality might be later than your version 1.23.1.

Comment: I want to download new version vscode and after install it, I'll see if the problem is resolved. @Mark

Answer (score 0):

You should get these out of the box.  I would be curious about your node installation.  And I'd lean towards saying using TypeScript in VS Code it is much more friendly in terms of intelli-sense. You can then install type(s) files .d.ts which TypeScript will refer to for intelli-sense, like for the Express Library or PM2 etc. However, the node.d.ts file is available by default in VS Code.  I would make sure that your version of Node is installed properly and on your Environmental Path. Here is the link to Intelli-Sense for VS Code,
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense